# Spring batch job jobrepository is null

Tags: spring, spring-batch

i make one job that like this.

```
<batch:job id="parentJob">
    <batch:step id="parentJob.step1">
        <batch:job ref="childJob" job-launcher="batchJobLauncher" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

the parentJob has childJob as a step.
and i assign batchJobLauncher as a childJob's launcher.

the problem is the spring initializing is fail with this error message.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JobRepository must be set
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractJob.java:109)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.JobParserJobFactoryBean.getObject(JobParserJobFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    ... 136 more
```

a job must have a reference of jobRepository but the parentJob doesn't.

i define job repository well and another job is fine with it.

if remove the childJob's specific launcher, spring initializing is success.

i debug spring code, i found JobParserJobFactoryBean class have null  JobRepository so the parentJob has null, too.

- version info

  - spring 3.2.0.RELEASE
  - spring-batch 2.1.8.RELEASE

what's the problem??

================================================================================
configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:hdp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop"
       xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop/spring-hadoop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd">

    <!-- required since Job is a class not an interface -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope" p:proxyTargetClass="true" />

    <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="databaseType" value="oracle" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="commonDataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="ISOLATION_DEFAULT" />
        <property name="lobHandler" ref="oracleLobHandler" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="nativeJdbcExtractor" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.OracleJdbc4NativeJdbcExtractor">
        <property name="connectionType" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="oracleLobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler">
        <property name="nativeJdbcExtractor" ref="nativeJdbcExtractor" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: A couple things: 1.  It would be good to upgrade both versions of Spring and Spring Batch.  2.  Can you post your complete configuration?  The configuration you have above doesn't have your `JobRepository` definition.

Comment: I'll post my configuration.

Comment: How are the two pieces of configuration associated?

Comment: sorry for late. applicationContext.xml(has jobRepository conf) import batch-context.xml(has spring batch job conf)

Comment: Are you sure both are being found?

Comment: before this problem, i wonder 3 level nested job is possible. for example, "grandParentJob", "parentJob" and childJob..

Comment: If you have a project or Gist I can take a look at I will, but I'm not seeing anything obvious from your configuration

Comment: now, i'm not having proper repository or project, if i can give it, i'll comment here.

Comment: I found one possible reason, if it has 3 degree nested job, the error is ocurred. (grandparent job (parent job (child job))). 2 degree nested job is ok. 3 degree nested job is impossible?

Comment: finally, I resolve this problem. I don't know exactly what is the main cause. but I can say that this is the bean dependency order problem. AA  bean has Job bean reference, and BB bean has AA bean references as List type. All reference is made by @Autowired. If I remove BB bean's List type reference, the problem is resolve. now I use the AA bean in BB bean using ApplicationContext's getBean.